# Properties of the adjoint of multiplication on Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded function with bounded first derivative. Then the multiplication operator $$H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow H^1(\mathbb{R}^n),$$
$$s\mapsto A_f x:=fx$$ 
is bounded, where $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

In two previous questions (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59095/adjoint-of-multiplication-operator-on-sobolev-space) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349742/square-root-of-multiplication-operator-on-sobolev-space)), it was asked whether the adjoint $A_f^*$ is also given by function multiplication. [This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349853/adjoint-of-the-multiplication-operator-on-a-sobolev-space/) by Iosif Pinelis shows that this is the case if and only if $f$ is a constant function.

The following are some further questions about the nature of $A_f^*$.

**Q1:** Does $A_f^*$ preserve the space $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

**Q2:** Is $A_f^*$ a pseudodifferential operator?

**Q3:** Would the answer to either of the above change if $\mathbb{R}^n$ is replaced by a compact manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\overline{f}$ denote the complex conjugate of $f$, and let $A_{\overline{f}}$ be the associated multiplication operator. For $g,h\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have:
\begin{align} 
\langle g, A_fh\rangle_{H^1}&=\langle g,(1+\Delta)A_fh\rangle_{L^2}\\
& = \langle A_{\overline{f}}(1+\Delta)g,h\rangle_{L^2}\\
& = \langle (1+\Delta)^{-1}A_{\overline{f}}(1+\Delta)g,h\rangle_{H^1}.
\end{align}

Thus $A_f^*=(1+\Delta)^{-1}A_{\overline{f}}(1+\Delta)$, a pseudodifferential operator. So the answers to the first two questions are both "yes". Since the proof works equally well on a manifold, the answer to the third question is "no".